# What unit of measurement is rxwaveform from the GEDI L1B dataset in?

Tags: remote-sensing, lidar, lidar-full-waveform

Rxwaveform is listed in GEDI's data level product L1B's data dictionary as "*The corrected receive (RX) waveforms. Use rx_sample_count and rx_sample_start_index to identify the location of each waveform.*
" This can also be seen in the attached image. I understand that waveforms are typically measured by amplitude as a function of time(or height), but are the values listed in rxwaveforms amplitudes? It doesn't explicitly say amplitude in the data dictionary, and what unit of measurement is amplitude in (if it is indeed amplitude). The second image is the data values of rxwaveform in matlab; and what is the significance of rx_sample_count in relation to rxwaveform?[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK rxwaveform is a count from the ADC (analog to digital converter). This is, the GEDI must have an analog sensor which measures the returning photons as some signal, but it seems that it is not calibrated to any form of known measurable energy, instead it is just transforming the analog signal to some digital count.

As rxwaveform is variable (the higher above ground artifacts there are more information in the rxwaveform for the footprint) you need to use rx_sample_start_index and rx_sample_count to know where the data is.

For example, say we have this data:

| shot_number | rx_sample_start_index | rx_sample_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 19640119100108615 | 1 | 760 |
| 19640119300108616 | 761 | 755 |
| 19640119500108617 | 1516 | 760 |
| 19640119700108618 | 2276 | 765 |
| 19640119900108619 | 3041 | 759 |
| 19640120100108620 | 3800 | 759 |
| 19640120300108621 | 4559 | 791 |
| 19640120500108622 | 5350 | 759 |
| 19640120700108623 | 6109 | 763 |
| 19640120900108624 | 6872 | 776 |
| 19640121100108625 | 7648 | 823 |
| 19640121300108626 | 8471 | 767 |
| 19640121500108627 | 9238 | 778 |
| 19640121700108628 | 10016 | 762 |
| 19640121900108629 | 10778 | 776 |
| 19640122100108630 | 11554 | 777 |

Then if I want to retrieve the waveform for the `shot_number` 19640120100108620 (6th row), I would need to slice the `rx_waveform` starting from `rx_sample_start_index` with `rx_sample_count` elements, so from 3800 to (3800 + 759).